# how do i glob for s specific set of files

Tags: regex, node.js, glob

All example I have found of file globbing only show character substitution, not alternation. I have the desire to glob a subset of files and want to do so by name. It seems it should be possible. Below are two examples of what I have tried.

```
['test/functional/**/(login|account|productManagement)-spec.*']
['test/functional/**/\b(login|account|productManagement)\b-spec.*']
```

Of course, the following does work as expected.

```
['test/functional/**/(login|account|productManagement)-spec.*']
```

This is javascript code running in node.js.

If it is not clear, I am expecting to find:
login-spec.*
account-spec.*
productManagement-spec.*

We have a large suite of protractor tests. Some fail randomly when running locally. Okay, that should be fixed, but it is an environmental thing and the obvious fix will slow down the whole test run. It is far simpler to run them, identify those that have failed, then re-run.

Comment: where are you doing the globbing? not all glob implementations have a full regex engine.

Comment: Globbing uses `{x,y,z}` for alternation, not `(x|y|z)`.

Comment: @MarcB updated my question specifying where it is being run.

Comment: @Barmar ['test/functional/**/{login|account|productManagement}-spec.*'] did not find any of the three files.

Comment: Maybe because you used `{x|y|z}` instead of `{x,y,z}`

Comment: @ThomasAyoub well, i'll be! paying attention to detail makes a difference.

Comment: Yes. Sorry that was not clear.